# Why $Hom_{R}(R^n,M) \cong M^n$ holds?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$. Let $M$ be module over $R$.
Then, how can I formally prove $Hom_{R}(R^n,M) \cong M^n$ holds ?
Here, $Hom_{R}(R^n,M)$ is set of all morphism of $R$ modules from $R^n$ to $M$.

I think to make map from $M^n$ is good, from ($x_1,x_2,・・・,x_n$)$\in M^n$, I'm stuck with making element of $Hom_{R}(R^n,M)$.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is $R_K$ here?

Comment: Sorry, that was typo, they are all $R$.

Comment: Use the standard basis $e_1,\dots,e_n$ of $R^n$.

Comment: There's a quick method then, but it uses some machinery. You have $\mathrm {Hom}(R^n,M)\cong (R^n)^*\otimes M\cong R^n\otimes M\cong M^n$ but I guess you are looking for something more simple?

Comment: Could you tell me what is * ?

Comment: And why your first $\cong$ holds ?

Comment: $N^\ast=\hom(N,R)$ is the dual module. There is a homomorphism $N^\ast\otimes M\to\hom(N,M)$ given by $\eta(-)\otimes m\mapsto \eta(-)m$. I'm blanking at the moment about in what generality it is an isomorphism.

Comment: @runway44 It is an isomorphism if at least one of the two modules in question is projective and finitely generated, so it works when one of them is $R^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In group theory, you probably encountered the fact every homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{Z}\to G$ to another group $G$ is determined by where it sends the cyclic generator $1$, which can go anywhere, and thus such homomorphisms are in one=to-one correspondence with the elements of $G$ (via $\phi\leftrightarrow\phi(1)$, and you can reconstruct $\phi$ from $\phi(1)$ via $\phi(n)=n\phi(1)$.).

It's the same idea here. Every $R$-module map $R^n\to M$ is determined by where it sends the "basis vectors" of $R^n$, which can go anywhere (independently). Thus, show $\phi\leftrightarrow(\phi(e_1),\cdots,\phi(e_n))$ is an additive bijection between $\hom(R^n,M)$ and $M^n$ (and indeed, is an $R$-module isomorphism if we are given $R$ is commutative). Here $e_1=(1,0,\cdots,0)$, etc.

Note that given $\vec{\phi}=(\phi(e_1),\cdots,\phi(e_n))$, the value of $\phi(r_1,\cdots,r_n)$ is determined for all $\vec{r}\in R^n$ by "extending linearly" ($R$-linearly, that is). Do you see how? (*Hint*. Write $\vec{r}=r_1e_1+\cdots+r_ne_n$ and remember we want $\phi$ to be an $R$-module homomorphism.)